# HTACCESS catching the filename as the request param

Tags: .htaccess

I have this htaccess rule to redirect my page to data_parser.php

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^main/([^/]+)$ data_parser.php?rand_code=$1 [nc]
```

when i print the request in data_parser.php the rand_code value turns out to be the filename of the page. For example url: http://mysite.com/main/ran12345. When print_r, this is the value i would see

```
[rand_code] => data_parser.php
```

instead of,

```
[rand_code] => ran12345
```

It's getting the filename, what am i doing wrong with my rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try adding this in front of your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !data_parser.php
```

Because what looks like is happening is the request is looping through your rules more than once. The second time, the `([^/]+)` matches against data_parser.php.

Comment: yes, you are right its looping the rule. I tried adding the rewritecond that you suggested to. I cant get the right value still. The rand_code value is the next redirection page. When print_r, value became [rand_code] => index_data . And, this is my code in data_parser.php   if($row[randcode] == $rand_code)
{
 //do some stuff here
 echo "<script type='text/Javascript'>window.location.href='index_data.php';</script>";
}
else{
 echo "<script type='text/Javascript'>alert('Ops! something went wrong');</script>";
}

Comment: @user1149244 Or you could try: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rand_code`